# Creating a cache memory benchmark in VHDL

Tags: benchmarking, vhdl, cpu-architecture

I have a working VHDL design for Data&Instruction Caches. I want to evaluate it (find miss rates and so) with a testbench.

So I want to know how to create random requests to the caches? and how to make them favor some type of locality or have a pattern (like sequential access but with occasional random jumps in a program for example)?

In other words, how to make a VHDL Benchmark to evaluate the cache designs in different conditions and memory access patterns?

Comment: Is the CPU on the cache system available for simulation also?  In that case you can simply try to execute some representative part of program on the CPU and then connect information about the cache behavior.  That is the method that CPU system developers (e.g. MIPS) use in order to optimize the system for specific code snippets (e.g. Dhrystone).  Simulation will be fast enough to determine system behavior, in special if some code with loops are executed.

Comment: @MortenZdk unfortunately there is no CPU availabe, The cache design is part of complete processor design that still lacks a complete CPU and a compiler.
It is not yet possible to compile codes or run it on a CPU.

Comment: If the CPU and compiler is not available yet, then it gets harder to make some realistic access patterns for the cache system, since system behavior and thereby also cache efficiency depends on CPU features like load scheduling, out-of-order execution, multi-threading, and compiler features like optimization, instruction reordering, etc.  So it sounds like you must create some expected statistical access pattern in simulation, and then measure cache performance based on this.  VHDL `math_real.uniform` is a good function to use for getting random value in a test bench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the types of cache patterns you would like to see, and you should be able to code them fairly easily in your testbench using IEEE.MATH_REAL.uniform.

To take your example of sequential access with occasional random jumps:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use IEEE.MATH_REAL.all;

entity ...

architecture ...
    signal cache_read : std_logic := '0';
    signal cache_addr : unsigned(31 downto 0) := (others=>'0');

    ...
begin
    sequential_and_jumps: process
            variable seed1, seed2 : positive := 42;
            variable rand         : real;
            variable loops        : integer;
            variable addr         : integer;
    begin
        cache_read <= '0';
        wait until reset='0' and rising_edge(clk);

        -- Starting address.
        addr := 0;

        -- Continual repeated accesses.
        loop
            -- Randomly jump to a new address between 0x0 and 0x10000
            -- with a chance of 10%.
            uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
            if(rand < 0.1) then
                uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
                addr := integer(trunc(rand * real(16#10000#)));
            end if;

            -- Wait 0-15 cycles prior to the cache request.
            uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
            loops := integer(trunc(rand*16.0));
            for i in 1 to loops loop
                wait until rising_edge(clk);
            end loop;

            -- Randomly request 1-32 words.
            uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
            loops := integer(trunc(rand*32.0)) + 1;
            for i in 1 to loops loop
                cache_addr <= to_unsigned(addr, cache_addr'length);
                cache_read <= '1';
                wait until rising_edge(clk);
                cache_read <= '0';
                -- Assumes word addresses.
                -- For byte addresses, increment by e.g. 4 for 32-bit words.
                addr := addr + 1;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Other access patterns can be achieved in a similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

For getting random numbers, use the [OSVVM - Open source, VHDL verification methodology](http://osvvm.org/) library.

To get your "interesting patterns", you could make use of the cache access data presented in Hennesey and Patterson's classic [Computer Architecture](http://store.elsevier.com/Computer-Architecture/John-Hennessy/isbn-9780123838728/) to create realistic probabilities of a variety of small and large block sizes and separations.